# Jython: How do you setColor() to hexadecimal Color?

Tags: colors, hex, jython

I've tried using the setColor() function to change a pixel to a hexadecimal color, but to no avail.

For example, setColor(getPixel(targetPic, x, y), 0xff1a44c3).

It's saying that the second parameter is not a color(0xff1a44c3). How do I get hexadecimals to work as colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java there is `java.awt.Color` with `Color(int rgb)` constructor.

Try with:

```
setColor(getPixel(targetPic, x, y), Color(0xff1a44))
```

or:

```
my_red = Color(0xff1a44)
setColor(getPixel(targetPic, x, y), my_red)
```

In Java such code should looks like:

```
setColor(getPixel(targetPic, x, y), new Color(0xff1a44))
```

or:

```
Color my_red = new Color(0xff1a44)
setColor(getPixel(targetPic, x, y), my_red)
```

Comment: It's saying color isn't defined. I thought all the color-related functions were ready to go in jython?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with strange hex color value. I have shortened it to 0xff1a44 which is shade of red. You can also try with code where color is defined in separate variable. It would be nice to see more of your code and exact error message?